# Java Android VPN PPTP protocol programming

Tags: java, android, protocols, vpn, android-vpn-service

I would like to develop an Android VPN application with VpnService.Our server is ready.I just want to communicate with the PPTP protocol.I created a PPTP profile for this.I also used SystemProperties.To do this, the phone needs to be root.How can I communicate with the PPTP protocol using the VpnService without root?

**How to programmatically auto connect from Android app to VPN using PPTP protocol server IP, username and password)**

Comment: you will have to implement PPTP protocol on your own in your service.

Comment: Can you recommend source code for this ?
I tried that.I created a PPTP profile.I used SystemProperties.But the device needs to be root.I have to do this without root.